# Kernel - make menuconfig error

Tags: drivers, bash, kernel, scripts, compiling

Working with a Headless Raspberry PI 4 with an Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 LTS.. I am trying to configure the source kernel. I have installed libncurses-dev, kernel-package, qt4-dev-tools.

When I run 'make menuconfig' in the directory /linux-5.7, it shows:

```
  LEX     scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c
/bin/sh: 1: flex: not found
scripts/Makefile.host:9: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/lexer.lex.c] Error 127
Makefile:588: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

Lost on what to do, everything I have read hasn't helped so far. My goal is to start programming device drivers, and to do so I need a configured and built kernel source tree on disk.

Answer (score 10):

In the Ubuntu's [Build Your Own Kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) guide it is stated that you have to install following programs :

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses-dev flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf
```

to be able to compile the kernel from source successfully.

Answer (score 5):

`flex` is not installed. Install it by

```
sudo apt install flex
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will be helpful, but when making kernel modules you can receive this same error if the makefile in use uses the keyword SUBDIRS= which was eliminated after version 5.3 of the kernel. Instances of SUBDIRS= need to be replaced by M=

Again, this is for building modules and drivers, but I would be surprised if building the kernel did not require similar references depending on the tools being used.