# linux kernel - trying to cross compile on ubuntu (for rpi zero)

Tags: bash, kernel, compiling, gcc, arm

[fresh virtual box vm, using ubuntu 20.04, all updates made during install]

I just try to run **make bcmrpi_defconfig** on a linux kernel git repository

**patched for RT** :

```
wget https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.19/patch-4.19.127-rt55.patch.gz
zcat patch-4.19.127-rt55.patch.gz | patch -p1
```

but it say it **cannot find the arm compiler**...

```
phil@rt-linux-pi:~/linux$ /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
bash: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian
/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory

phil@rt-linux-pi:~/linux$ ls /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -lha
lrwxrwxrwx 1 phil phil 29 Jun 25 22:58 /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -> arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8.3
```

**I now realize arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc is nowhere to be found on the system**

**I get this error** :

```
make bcmrpi_defconfig
/bin/sh: 1: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
/bin/sh: 1: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: 26: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: 27: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: 29: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: 26: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: 27: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: 29: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
init/Kconfig:17: syntax error
init/Kconfig:16: invalid option
./scripts/clang-version.sh: 15: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
./scripts/gcc-plugin.sh: 11: /home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: not found
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/Makefile:104: bcmrpi_defconfig] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:534: bcmrpi_defconfig] Error 2
```

**I tried** :

- installing build essentials
- I installed these packages : libncurses-dev flex bison openssl libssl-dev dkms libelf-dev libudev-dev libpci-dev libiberty-dev autoconf
- I moded the PATH variable :

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin/
```

thanks for the time you'll spend on this question

regards

I follow this tutorial : http://www.frank-durr.de/?p=203

Comment: First off you have to [install all required packages](https://askubuntu.com/a/1245887/1001338).From the error it's clear that you haven't **bison** in your system. And how did you install the ARM version of GCC ? Is the directory ```/home/phil/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian/bin``` in your **$PATH** environment variable ? Try ```echo $PATH```.

Comment: I edited my questions with things you mentioned, yet , if I run the file compiler manualy it says 'no such file or directory', but it is there, as a soft link and in my PATH ...

Comment: I think it's better to install the gcc from repository.Then it will go to the standard directories and you'll be able to run it with ease.Follow [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1046033/1001338).

Comment: but it's gcc for RPI

Comment: I'll try another tutorial, this one is 'meh', and outdated

Comment: RPI architecture is ARM64 (aka aarch64).I don't think there would be any problem if you compile it with **gcc-9-aarch64-linux-gnu** for example.

Answer (score 0):

the official doc explains things a bit better and in a more "recent way" of doing things

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/kernel/building.md

first mod and source .bashrc file and add at the end :

```
if [ -d "$HOME/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$PATH:$HOME/tools/arm-bcm2708/arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin"
fi
```

to build kernel do :

```
sudo apt install git bc bison flex libssl-dev make libc6-dev libncurses5-dev

git clone --depth=1 --branch rpi-4.19.y https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux

cd linux
export KERNEL=kernel
make bcmrpi_defconfig

cd ..
git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools ~/tools

cd linux

make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- bcmrpi_defconfig
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf- zImage modules dtbs
```

hope this helps someone else too